# response.authResponse not returning true after facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to write a facebook login button. The below is my facebook javascript. Everything went well (i.e. popup window came out, facebook login prompt, etc), until i login successfully via facebook app, the line "alert('Login Failed!');" is executing. This is due to response.authResponse != 1. Can anyone help me on this?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId      : 'I placed my app id here', // App ID
     channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
     status     : true, // check login status
     cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
     xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
   });
};
// logs the user in the application and facebook
function fblogin(){
FB.getLoginStatus(function(r){
     if(r.status === 'connected'){
            window.location.href = 'fbconnect.php';
     }else{
        FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
              //if (response.perms)
                    alert('Success!');
                    window.location.href = 'fbconnect.php';
            } else {
                alert('Login Failed!');
              // user is not logged in
            }
     },{scope:'email'}); // which data to access from user profile
 }
});
}
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';                
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
//]]>
</script>
```

This is my login button

```
echo '<a href=# onclick="fblogin();">Facebook Login</a>';
```

Comment: You all can try it at http://utourpia.me/php/myprofile.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. Apparently the problem is that my Sandbox mode is on in my facebook app basic info. Turning that off would make the above code valid.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try this, don't test it with r.status === 'connected'

```
if (r.authResponse) {
    //user is already logged in and connected
    FB.api('/me', function (info) {
        login(response, info);
    });

} 
else {
    //user is not connected to your app or logged out
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function (info) {});
        } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization

        }
    }, {scope : 'email'});
}
```

Comment: one thing to note is that FB.login (or my facebook app) is not asking for user email permission even though i have set scope = email. Strange enough.